# How to integrate forget password api in swift4

Tags: ios, swift4

This is my first project ,which i am currently doing.Here,My task is integrating forget password api.I am not aware of doing forget password.Can anyone help me to do this task.If i know the process,how to do and how it works,Then it would be little easier to me.Thank in advance.

```
  @IBAction func resetbutton(_ sender: Any) {
   var email = emailtextfield.text
        if email == ""{
            let Alertcontroller = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Please Enter Email-Id", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let CancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            Alertcontroller.addAction(CancelAction)
            self.present(Alertcontroller, animated: true, completion: nil)
            print(Alertcontroller)

        }else {

            postParameters = ["email":email]
                    Alamofire.request(Constants.Forgetpassword, method: .post, parameters: postParameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers:nil).responseJSON {  response in
                        switch response.result {
                        case .success:
                            print(response)
                            if response.result.value != nil{

                            }

                            break
                        case .failure(let error):

                            print(error)
                        }
                    }

        }

   }
```

Comment: you need to just call forget password Api and you will get a response success or failure, that response need to display  to user. rest of the things will do from server side.

Comment: so no need to use any parse third party library??

Comment: what do you mean by parse third party library ?? please explain in detail

Comment: I have gone through this vedio.here they are using parse."https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-GdJRCb9ULI"

Comment: what you are using Parse or webservice ?

Comment: Now i am using Web services, which are giving by php people

Comment: okay i think you are using Webservice , have you used Alamofire for webservice call?

Comment: Have you implement any other webservice ? if yes then it is same like other webservice. you do not need to anything extra for forget password webservice.

Comment: yes I am using alamofire only.I tried to send url request like other requests.But here i am getting status code 400.Can you please check my code once.I am adding that code to my question.

Comment: please check below answer or share your API URL and required params

Comment: I tried with the below code,I am getting console response like "The message is: Invalid email.
"

Comment: it's a very simple message, you are trying with email id which is not registered as a user, so try with registered email id. it will work .

Comment: The thing is I already registered with same mail id .that mail only i used here

Comment: then you need to ask your php team members, please also check in postman with required params .

Comment: please share API URL and required params so i will check and let you know

Comment: I solved this yar...Thankyou so much for your help..

Comment: What was the issue and if you find any help from given solution then upvote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below steps for installing and creating pod file in your
 project.

1. https://blog.supereasyapps.com/cocoapods-tutorial-for-beginners-in-xcode-9-and-swift-4/ (Install cocoa pod for webservice call)
2. import Alamofire in your viewcontroller.
3. Call below function in forget password button click.

   ```
    func apiCallForgotPassword(){
       let todosEndpoint: String = "YOUR_API_URL"
       //pass your required params
       let dictParam: [String: Any] = ["email": "test@test.com"]
       Alamofire.request(todosEndpoint, method: .post, parameters: dictParam,
                         encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
           .responseJSON { response in
               guard response.result.error == nil else {
                   // got an error in getting the data, need to handle it
                   print("error calling POST on /todos/1")
                   print(response.result.error!)
                   return
               }
               // make sure we got some JSON since that's what we expect
               guard let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any] else {
                   print("didn't get todo object as JSON from API")
                   print("Error: \(response.result.error)")
                   return
               }
               // get and print the success message
               guard let message = json["message"] as? String else {
                   print("Could not get todo title from JSON")
                   return
               }
               print("The message is: " + message)
           }
    }
   ```